# Laravel-echo showing 401 (Unauthorized) for private channel except one user

Tags: reactjs, laravel, pusher, laravel-echo, laravel-broadcast

I am getting 401 (Unauthorized) status for laravel private channel from reactJS.

**This is working for userId=1 but returning 401 for all other users.**

Here is the code for Laravel

```
class BroadcastServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Broadcast::routes([
            "middleware" => ['api', 'jwt.auth'],
            "prefix" => "api"
        ]);

        require base_path('routes/channels.php');
    }
}


class AppointmentEvent implements ShouldBroadcastNow
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;
    public $appointment;
    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($appointment)
    {
        $this->appointment = $appointment;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('App.User.' . $this->appointment->patient_id);
    }
}


Broadcast::channel('App.User.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
    return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;
});
```

And here is the react code

```
const token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("patientToken"));
const options = {
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: '1c**************61',
    cluster: 'ap2',
    encrypted: true,
    authEndpoint: 'http://localhost/heal/api/broadcasting/auth', 
    auth: {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        Accept: 'application/json',
      },
    },
  };
  window.Echo = new Echo(options);

var p = localStorage.getItem("patientId");
      window.Echo.private(`App.User.${p}`).listen('ConfirmAppointmentEvent', (e) => {
        alert("Doctor accepted your appointment")
        console.log(e)
      });
```

Working perfect for user_id 1, but not for others
I did uncomment `App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,`

**Laravel version 7.30.0**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

works for me

AuthEndpointController

```
    public function auth(Request $request)
    {
        $pusher = new Pusher(env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'), env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'), env('PUSHER_APP_ID'));
        if($request->request->get('channel_name') === 'private-App.User.' . $request->user()->id) {
            return $pusher->socket_auth($request->request->get('channel_name'), $request->request->get('socket_id'));
        }
        return response()->json([], 400);
   }
```

```js
const token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("patientToken"));
const options = {
  broadcaster: 'pusher',
  key: '1c4c1546ef4c02340c61',
  cluster: 'ap2',
  forceTLS: true,
  authEndpoint: 'http://localhost/heal/api/broadcasting/auth', 
  auth: {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
  },
};
window.Echo = new Echo(options);
var p = localStorage.getItem("patientId");
  window.Echo.private(`App.User.${p}`).listen('ConfirmAppointmentEvent', (e) => {
    alert("Doctor accepted your appointment")
    console.log(e)
  });
```

Comment: Where can I get that AuthEndpointController?

Comment: check this controller https://github.com/dedeardiansya/ab-v2/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/Api/Account/PusherController.php

Comment: and add this in route/api.php Route::post('heal/api/broadcasting/auth', 'PusherController@broadcast');